# XPage file upload control loses filename on refresh

Tags: xpages

I'm sure I must be just missing something simple here but I've searched everywhere for an answer and no luck.

I have a bog standard file upload control on my xpage showing initially the standard "No file chosen", I select the "Choose file" button which overwrites the "No file chosen" with the selected filename - all good! BUT on any subsequent partial or full refresh of the page the filename is disappearing and reverting to "No file chosen". If I submit the form anyway the file is still uploaded correctly to the server but this is obviously no good for the user who thinks they have to reselect the file.

Can someone just tell me what I'm doing wrong here??

```
<xp:fileUpload id="songAlbumUpload1" value="#{submitfile.File1}">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

Note this was my latest attempt using a full refresh but I've tried all other partial refresh options too.  Also my upload control is in a formTableRow so I tried moving it out into the main panel but the issue still occurs.

(I have also discovered the bug where a refresh ends up uploading multiple instances of the same file which as I understand it is fixed by a partial refresh of the panel the upload control is contained in - but of course this required refresh then causes the above issue anyway)!

Many thanks.

Comment: Once the file is uploaded, that edit box is empty again - to accept another file to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Frantisek, upon refresh the fileUpload returns to a "No File Chosen" display indicating its ready to upload another file.  Try removing the eventHandler to preserve the uploaded filename:

```
    <xp:fileUpload id="songAlbumUpload1" value="#{submitfile.File1}"></xp:fileUpload>
```

Or add a fileDownload and bind it to the same RTF to display the status of the uploaded files.

```
    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1" value="#{submitfile.File1}" displayLastModified="true"
        allowDelete="true" hideWhen="false" style="width:100.0%">
    </xp:fileDownload>
```

Comment: So I was being daft after all...although in my defence I assumed that as I have Multiple disabled it would retain the filename until submission! Thank you Frantisek and Paul - the additional control is exactly what I need.